# "Учившихся", "приехавших" — падеж

Tags: морфология

Какой будет падеж у слов *"учившихся"* и *"приехавших"* в предложении:

*Такими словами встретил старый Бульба двух сыновей своих, учившихся в киевской бурсе и приехавших уже на дом к отцу.*

Comment: Винительный. Встретил - кого?, что? А в чем сложность?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

> *...встретил сыновей, учившихся... и приехавших...*
>
> Какой будет падеж у слов *"учившихся"* и *"приехавших"*?..

Такой же, как и здесь:

*...встретил **дочь**, учивш**ую**ся... и приехавш**ую**...*

ВИНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае правильнее говорить **не о падеже, а  о падежной форме  определений "учившихся, приехавших".**

Сравним два варианта:

(1) Заданное предложение: Такими словами встретил старый Бульба  **двух сыновей  своих, учившихся** в киевской бурсе и **приехавших** уже на дом к отцу.

(2)К Тарасу Бульбе приехали **два взрослых  сына**, учившихся в киевской бурсе.

1) **В первом случае** количественный оборот "два сына" со значением В.п. используется в форме Р.п. "двух сыновей", таким образом выражается одушевленность существительного. (Отметим, что категорию одушевленности выражают не все числительные,  а только два, три, четыре и собирательные числительные).

**Все определения также имеют форму Р.п.** (своих, учившихся,  приехавших), согласование в Р.п.

2) **Во втором случае** количественный оборот "два сына" имеет значение и  форму И.п., но определения по-прежнему стоят в форме Р.п.

**Правило:** Форма определения  в количественно-именных словосочетаниях с числительными два, три, четыре зависит  ОТ РОДА имени существительного:

два высоких дерева, три больших ведра – Р. п. прилагательных для сущ. м.р. и ср.р. (это основная форма);

три высокие пальмы, две большие ложки – И. п. прилагательных для сущ. ж. р. (эта форма применяется не всегда, иногда используется основная форма Р.п.).

**Примеры.** В астрономии все галактики делят на три большие группы. Завтра в Брюсселе пройдут сразу две важные встречи. Три счастливых дня было у меня.  Два огромных  дерева стояли по сторонам.

Answer (score -2):

"Учившихся" и "приехавших"  - причастия-определения к слову "сыновей".

А дальше - **[правило](http://edu.glavsprav.ru/info/prichastie/)**:

> Падеж, число, род причастий определяется по падежу, числу, роду
>   существительного, к которому причастие относится.

Значит, осталось определить падеж слова "сыновей", - оно отвечает на вопрос "кого?", а это вопрос и винительного и родительного падежа.

Сайт ["Как просто"](http://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-105520-kak-opredelit-vinitelnyy-ili-roditelnyy-padezh) предлагает такую подсказку:

> Замените существительное во множественном числе неодушевленным
>   существительным в той же форме и определяйте падеж по аналогии.
>   Например, «Знаю (кого?) людей» замените на «Знаю (что?) имена».
>   «Имена» – это винительный падеж множественного числа. Пример с
>   родительным падежом: «Знаю адреса (кого?) друзей» замените на «Знаю
>   адреса (чего?) учреждений». «Учреждений» – родительный падеж
>   множественного числа.

"Встретить двух" (неважно кого) уже указывает на одушевлённость - иначе было бы *встретить два* или *две*.

Пробуем подставить неодушевлённое существительное в предложении, сходном с заданием.

*С удивлением встретила я два мнения, не совпадавшие с моим.*

*Тарас встретил у дороги две берёзы, склонившиеся к воде.*

Если эти выкладки верны, то в Вашем предложении (сыновей, учившихся и приехавших) - родительный падеж.

Comment: Ничего я, похоже, не понимаю в падежах, если только у Вас действительно всё правильно. В Ваших примерах, Галина, разве *встретил(а) чего, а не что?* Почему тогда родительный?

Comment: Тёмыч, ищи ответ! Примеры - с заменой одушевлённости на наоборот. Поэтому в примерах - винительный... Не могу найти онлайн-склонение "два сына"! Как ни кручу, а винительный и родительный совпадают!

Comment: В.: встретил  две берёзы, склонившиеся; Р.: не встречал двух берёз, склонившихся... Может, надо род существительного менять, чтобы проверить?

Comment: Не встречал — родительный, а встретил — винительный вроде. А почему он должен меняться при замене одушевлённости?